# Split an array of ids and save it as individual rows in table

Tags: 7

I managed to get all ids from a table using query in drupal. I got the array of ids. I'm struggling to insert all the ids in another table as individual rows. As Im new to the drupal concepts,its very difficult for me to figure it out. Any help is appreciable.:)

Comment: Although I'm not very experienced with the database side of Drupal, it would be really helpful to others if you could include a little more details and your drupal version.

Comment: a simple solution could be to loop thru the array using a simple "foreach" and insert every record. Something like:

```
foreach ($list as $row) {
drupal_write_record('table_name', $data('field_name' => $row['id']));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It helped to find the solution @redhatlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [db_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7.x) in your module OR [drupal_write_record](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7.x)

E.g: drupal 7 code

```
 //Assuming your array is like
 /*
   $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,....);
 */

  // Traversing ids by using foreach loop
  foreach($ids_array as $key=>$value){
       $custom_table_data = array(
            'id'=>$value,// id value
            'column1'=>'..'
        );

       // INSERT INTO {table_name} (field_1, field_2, ...) VALUES ('ABC', '123', ....)
        $nid = db_insert('table_name') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields($custom_table_data)
        ->execute();

        // OR using drupal_write_record... 
        drupal_write_record('table_name', $custom_table_data);
  }
```